# Fine design for the parts of a book (decoration, font, size, position) for the parts of a book?

Tags: book-design, parts, fancy

I am writing a math book and I want to structure it into **parts**, **chapters**, **sections** and **subsections**.

I would like to **start each part** with a **decorated style**, for example, with a light gray geometric background, also controlling the font type and size, as well as its position on the page.

I will appreciate ideas on this.

Comment: Look around for questions involving titlesec package for a start.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Things that might help: `textpos`, `fontspec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoir` class provides many means of controlling the appearance of `part` pages. See **section 6.4 Book and Part headings** in the manual (`texdoc memoir`).